# Linearizing an expression involving exponentials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, exponential-function

How can I linearize $f(x) = A(1-\text{exp}(Bx))$? I tried to take the natural logaritm, but could not find something that looks like linear. I am trying to find a fitting curve for this by hand. $A$ and $B$ are real constants.

Comment: Linearise near which point? What are $A,B$? Matrices, reals?

Comment: In general, like log(f(x))=lnA+Bx. A and B are real constants.

Comment: Except if the data cover a very small range, it does not seems (at least to me) to be a good idea. On the other side, you could linearize the equations which will be giving iterates for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $\log(1-(f(x)/A))=Bx$.

Answer (score 0):

For linearizing any function $f(x)$ about a point $x_0$, use: $$f(x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)\frac{df}{dx}(x_0)$$
But beware: this approximation works only for points close to $x_0$